# Label allow user input

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, submenu

I am creating a text box programmatically, but the problem that I am facing is that when I am inserting it in an array as an object to be vied on top of a list, the allowed type is label. Hence when the text box is displayed, the program does not allow the text box for user input. Is there a way to fix this? I have already tried to change the type to text and I get undefined.

```
searchArray = [];
//creating the text box and placing it in a variable
var textBox = "<input type='text' placeholder='Search Client Code'>";

searchArray.push({label: textBox });

//diaplaying the text box in a context menu sub menu
return{
    "Search" : {
        label : "Search",
        action: true,                            
        "submenu": searchArray,
        disabled: false
    }
}

*****************************************************
UPDATE

var searchArray = [];

var textBox = "<input type='text' placeholder='Search Client Code'>";
textBox.push({label: something});

//this array is used to insert the textbox and also the clients afterwards
new_array = [];
new_array.push(searchArray[0]);

//the below push is used in a for loop that loops each client,
//so I am just putting it here just for reference
***
new_array.push(itemDisp[i]);
***

if(...){
    var obj = {
        "DuplicateFor" : {
            label : "Duplicate for",
            action: true,                            
            "submenu": new_array,
            disabled: false
        }
    }
    document.body.innerHTML = obj['DuplicateFor']['submenu'][0].label
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will create the input successfully and it takes input as well

```js
var searchArray = [];
//creating the text box and placing it in a variable
var textBox = "<input type='text' placeholder='Search Client Code'>";

searchArray.push({
  label: textBox
});

//diaplaying the text box in a context menu sub menu
var obj = {
  "Search": {
    label: "Search",
    action: true,
    "submenu": searchArray,
    disabled: false
  }
}
console.log(obj)

document.body.innerHTML = obj['Search']['submenu'][0].label
```

Comment: what have you changed exactly please?

Comment: Assigned the search object to a variable inserted it in the body tag

Comment: ya. How you were calling it before, you haven't included that in the question?

Comment: I was calling it in the return. I will include that right now!

Comment: your return statement wont work, because it does not tell the DOM that you want to add something to it. Use the document.. method

Comment: still somehow it doesn't work and I did it exactly like yours :/

Comment: sometimes I get cannot read property of 'haschildnodes' of undefined and the text is displayed in another page. And most of the time it is displayed but not work

Comment: In the question.

Comment: any clue? @ellipsis